# Location of a Windows service *not* in my project

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

If I right-click and choose Properties on a service (like, say, Plug and Play) in the Services dialog, I get several pieces of information, including "Path to executable".  For Plug and Play (in Vista) this is:

C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch

Is there some way I can get this same piece of information using .NET code if I know the service name (and/or the display name)?

(I can't use `GetExecutingAssembly()` because I'm not running the service from my project.)

Answer (score 3):

Another option, without the interop, would be a WMI lookup (or registry - bit hacky!).

Here's a quick example, based on [this code](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2005_4_0_0_505060/Get-path-for-install-service.htm):

```
private static string GetServiceImagePathWMI(string serviceDisplayName)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName = '{0}'", serviceDisplayName);
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        foreach(ManagementObject service in search.Get())
        {
            return service["PathName"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This information is in the [QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684950(VS.85).aspx) structure.  You will need to use P/Invoke to get it out.

The basic process is:

Call OpenSCManager to get a handle to the services managed.

Call OpenService to get a handle to the service.

Call QueryServiceConfig to get the QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG structure.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the WMI class `Win32_Service` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the `PathName`.

This works:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service");
foreach(ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
{
    if(mo.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() == "<Short name of your service>")
    {
        return mo.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString().Trim('"');
    }
}
```

If you have any issue related to Reference then add a reference of [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your project.